# Incorrect main method running in visual studio

Tags: c++, eclipse, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to do some tutorial C++ programs to familiarize myself with the language.  I'm using Visual Studio 2010.  I have a Visual Studio solution with two projects - I'll just call them projectA and projectB. Each project has a source file with its own main method.  However, when I try to run the program in projectB, the program in projectA runs instead.  I'm coming from an Eclipse IDE where projects separate the programs.  I've some msdn articles on solutions and projects, but I haven't seen anything about being unable to have multiple source files with main methods in them.  Can someone help to clarify the Visual Studio Solution/Project structure for me, please.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the project you want to run, and select **Set as StartUp Project**

Comment: So, each Solution can only have one program as the main program, even if they are in different projects?

Comment: This is just a shortcut to tell Visual Studio which project to launch when you press the Run or Debug buttons.  You can manually launch any project by right clicking and selecting **Debug - Start New Instance** or you can change the StartUp project whenever you like

Comment: There's logic behind this: the second main produces a second .EXE, which is typically a helper process (e.g. runs as UAC elevated process to perform some admin task). The first EXE would then start the second EXE, so Visual Studio only needs to start the first EXE.

Answer (score 1):

You have to right click on the project and `"Set as Startup Project"` to tell Visual Studio which project you want to actually run.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is a nice simple fix:  if you look at your solution and have both projects open, you should be able to right click one of them and set it as default (Set as Startup Project), (which sounds like at the moment is set to projectA).

I have highlighted the relevant option in the menu picture:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Either you can right click on the project in the Project Explorer and select Set As StartUp Project or you can use meny item Project and also select Set StartUp Project.